# Visual Studio 2010 error: Declaration is incompatible (note: declarations are identical)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

my problem is in regards to a class Stack. My function definitions in my Stack.h file and the corresponding functions in my Stack.cpp file appear to be exactly the same to me and yet I get an error message from VS2010 stating that they are incompatible (push, pop and getTop only).

Here is my .h file:

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H
#include "Potion.h"

class Stack
{
public:
// constructors and destructor
Stack(int stackSize);
Stack(Stack& thisStack);
~Stack();

// stack operations
bool isEmpty() const;
bool isFull() const;

bool push(const Potion& potion);

bool pop(const Potion& potion);

void getTop(Potion& potion);

private:

Potion* items;
int top;
int sCount;
int sSize;
};

#endif
```

and here is my (obviously incomplete) .cpp file

```
#include "Stack.h"
#include "Potion.h"

Stack::Stack(int stackSize) const :
top(-1),
sSize(stackSize),
sCount(0)
{

}

Stack::Stack(Stack& thisStack)
{
}

Stack::~Stack()
{
}

bool Stack::push(const Potion& potion) 
{
    return true;
}

bool Stack::pop(const Potion& potion)
{
    return true;
}

bool Stack::isEmpty() const
{
    return true;
}

bool Stack::isFull() const
{
    return true;
}

void Stack::getTop(Potion& potion)
{

}
```

I get the error message for push, pop, and getTop only, and only those words are underlined in red, not any of the rest of the functions. Any insight would be appreciated very much. Thank you all

Comment: `push` and `pop` does not return anything. `getTop` returns a value when it should not.

Comment: I just slapped some "return true"s in push and pop and deleted the contents of getTop and the errors are still there

Comment: `pop` does not match the declaration either. Sorry I dont know enough of C++ to help further. Just pointed out some obvious issues.

Comment: Is this a compilation error, or is it only IntelliSense? Don't rely on IntelliSense, it's just an approximation.

Answer (score 0):

"Exactly the same"??? Really? Here's one example. Declaration:

```
class Stack
{
  ... 
  Stack(int stackSize);
```

Definition

```
Stack::Stack(int stackSize) const
```

Where did that `const` come from? What is it doing there? That is not even mentioning that declaring constructors `const` is illegal.

Now let's take a look at `pop`. Declaration

```
bool Stack::pop(Potion& potion);
```

Definition

```
bool Stack::pop(Potion& potion) const
{
  return true;
}
```

Again, a `const` suddenly appears in the definition. Why?

Comment: whoa, getting feisty over there. that poor question mark key needs a break. I did fix all of that though, and I'm still getting the exact same errors. I had it all correct to begin with but I'm not 100% confident with this stuff, so it was all mixed up in the samples above because I was just trying different things to see if anything would work. I appreciate you taking the time to respond, thank you for that. Problem's still up in the air though :/

Comment: @BabaSvoloch: If you "fixed" something, post real code. Telepathy and clairvoyance is in short supply these days.